# JAVA Mobile Devices - storing data locally

Tags: java, android, mobile, blackberry

What is the best way to store a data set locally on a mobile device for further processing in Java?

The data set is going to be retrieved using SOAP and will consists of about 50 to 100 'objects'. Each object is like an email thread - main message followed by several updates (mainly text, occasionally graphics).

Expected actions on the 'objects':

- read
- add new update / send an update to the server
- change status / send an update to the server

Is it better to operate directly on an xml file, implement a local data structure or perhaps use a database of some sort?

Target devices: Android & Blackberry. I would like to keep the solution as generic as possible to make it easier to reuse parts of the code the mentioned platforms.

Many thanks, Luke

Comment: The only built-in approach in common is SQLite, but the APIs are so different I doubt you can reuse much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on you:

If you want something fast - use [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) or Store it in XMl File.

If you want something easy to implement (but slower) - use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

If you are thinking about to use SQlite or Xml file than i will suggest you to use SQlite database because you need to perform such operation on the data.so reading from xml file and again writing it to file will be little slower than SQLite database.
Hope this helps.